# Пунктуация в предложениях по типу "Ну сколько их там(?) 5–6?" и ему подобных

Tags: грамматика, пунктуация

Уважаемые пользователи.

Имеется предложение *"Ну сколько DVD-дисков покупает в среднем человек за названный период(?) 5–6?"*, вводящее меня в заблуждение: не знаю, какой знак препинания необходимо поставить на месте указанного вопросительного знака в скобках, — запятую или тире. С одной стороны, и тире, и запятая могут выступать в роли уточняющего знака препинания, относясь к слову *"сколько"*. С другой — тире теоретически можно применить как средство, которое заменяет отсутствующий член предложения, восстанавливаемый из предшествующего предложения (*"Ну сколько DVD-дисков **покупает** в среднем человек за названный период? **Покупает** 5–6?"*).

Для понимания контекста даю сегмент оригинального текста — из него и было взято вызвавшее затруднения предложение:

> "Сегодня мир перегружен информацией. Каждые 365 дней выходит более
> миллиона DVD-дисков, и вряд ли ежегодно кто-то будет брать по 100–200
> из них. Ну сколько дисков в среднем покупает человек за названный
> период(?) 5–6?"

Заранее благодарю за ответы и помощь.

Comment: Я бы просто поставил знак вопроса, а "5-6" сделал бы отдельным предложением: "Ну сколько DVD-дисков покупает в среднем человек за названный период? 5–6?"

Comment: Иван, большое спасибо за предложенное решение. К нему крайне удобно прибегать в подобных ситуациях, и я сам думал о том, чтобы именно таким образом выстроить текст, однако хотелось узнать о расстановке знаков препинания в данном конкретном примере на будущее — пригодится и для внештатных эпизодов в работе, и для тех моментов, когда написанное хочется сделать более "разнообразным" (особенно если в нем фиксируется разговорная речь).

Как бы то ни было, один из пользователей уже дал подробный ответ.

Еще раз благодарю вас за комментарий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rhetorical question followed by an answer.

I couldn't find it codified explicitly in Rosenthal or Lopatin, but the em-dash prevails in usage, and that's what I would've used in your sentence:

> - Я всех беру!  Сколько их тут — пять?  Сгребай всех сюда, ко мне в сумку.
>   *[Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (2011-2015)]*
> - Маруся почему-то стала представлять себя в виде сосуда с жидкостью, сколько там — пять литров крови? *[Полина Волошина, Евгений Кульков. Маруся (2009)]*
> - Это ж не футбол!  Ну, сколько там свидетелей — ну, десять.  Самое большее — двадцать, — растопыривал пальцы, — вон их повели. *[Александр Терехов. Каменный мост (1997-2008)]*

Other authors do use the comma:

> - Видно, мамина дочка.  Ну сколько ей, от силы восемнадцать.  Как бы мои ребята не стали с ней кобелировать... " *[Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, ч. 1 (1960)]*
> - — Да какие там формальности: деньги заплачу, да и все.  Сколько там, двести тридцать девять?   — Сейчас посчитаем, — уклончиво ответил Александр. *[Николай Фохт. Антенны (1997) // «Столица», 04.03.1997]*

Others still do split the sentence and use the question mark:

> - За это время — сколько пройдет? час, два, три? — можно вскрыть десяток сейфов. *[Андрей Лазарчук. Все, способные держать оружие... (1995)]*
> - А он на своём поэтическом веку как долгом тёмном волоку — сколько их перенёс? триста? четыреста? *[А. И. Солженицын. Бодался теленок с дубом (1967-1974)]*

It looks like usage depends on how rhetorical the question is and how obvious the answer is.

You can use any of them: the comma, the em-dash, or the question mark (in order of the most to least rhetorical).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. You've really cleared that up. It's so nice to hear that I'm free to use any of the punctuation marks I've mentioned in the original post. As expected. I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте тире.

> Ну, сколько дисков в среднем покупает человек за названный период -
> 5–6?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! К такому решению в итоге и пришел.